# Play music from two apps simultaneously on Android

Tags: java, android, flutter

I would like to be able to play music/sounds from two different apps.

Is it possible to play sound from two apps on Android simultaneously without using some hack?

And if possible, is it possible for the user to select an option from my app to enable this option system wide?

Comment: What you're talking about is audio focus.  This has gone through changes in recent versions of Android.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus for details.

Comment: Thank you. I'll post up a solution once I've got it working.